# Nodejs Get Request Error

Tags: node.js, angular, angular-cli

I'm using the `MEAN stack` for an `angular 4` web application I'm making and I'm currently working on making calls to the `MongoDB` database. I had it working earlier, but now I'm getting the error:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404
>   (Not Found)

and I believe it's because the call is being made to

http://localhost:4200/api/users

while my database is running

http://localhost:3000/api/users.

How can I make sure that my calls are directed to port 3000?

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/docs/documentation/stories/proxy.md

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use proxy for that

create a file next to our project's package.json called proxy.conf.json with the content

```
{
  "/api": {
    "target": "http://localhost:3000",
    "secure": false
  }
}
```

Then edit the package.json

Change `"start": "ng serve",` to  `"start": "ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json",`

For more info [Check this link](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/docs/documentation/stories/proxy.md)

Comment: Thanks a lot, that did the trick. Do you know why this became a necessary work around when I didn't need to do it eariler?

Comment: This is necessary from the start you may be working on some other project which already set to proxy or may be api and ui project are running on same origin also mark it as accepted answer if it works for you